# Изменить высоту ячейки по нажатию на определенную кнопку

Tags: ios, uitableview

Есть таблица с кастомной ячейкой, на которой есть картинка и кнопка. Нужно, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку картинка отодвигалась вниз (с расширением ячейки вниз на столько же пикселей) и на месте сдвига появлялся лейбл с текстом, при чем текст может быть разной длинны, а следовательно и количество строк в лейбле будет различным, а отсюда и сдвиг для каждой в отдельности ячейки - разный.

Если работать через cell.frame то ячейка увеличивается, но заползает на следующую ,а такого быть не должно. Есть какие либо идеи по этому поводу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возвращаем из

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

нужную новую высоту, дальше

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Изучите работу табличного представления. Нельзя так просто взять и поменять размер ячейки. UITableView наследуется от UIScrollView, следовательно ей нужно знать размер contentSize`а до начала каких либо действий. И следовательно размер ячейки будет влиять на всю структуру UITableView, т.к. общий размер contentSize тоже поменяется.
Табличка перед первым показом на экран дергает, через делегат, размер каждой ячайки методом:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

я в этот метод заталкиваю новые параметры селки в самой селке узнаю свой размер после вызова метода:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews; // метод вызываю в селке после установки моделей данных.
```

после вызова этого метода я получаю реальный  размер селки после чего я возвращаю его в делегат.

Все самое сложное сделано. Остальное осталось вызвать перегрузку селки:

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

ну и все теперь осталось сделать кастомную анимацию в методе:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

[Тут можно глянуть реализацию метода](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/animating-uitableview-cells/)